# Ureadahead - how to clear it's cache?

Tags: boot, ureadahead

I am using Xubuntu 11.10 on old laptop with Pentium M and 1GB RAM. Please tell me, how to clear ureadahead cache, so I can build an "index" of files again, I would like to improve my system boot time, which takes about 1 minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean **ureadahead**.

If so, remove any **pack** files in the */var/lib/ureadahead* directory.

Comment: Exactly! I was wrong, I mean ureadahead of course. Sorry about that, and thanks for solution!

Comment: Besides `debugfs`, I've `home.pack` and `pack` in `/var/lib/ureadahead`. Did you mean "any pack files" was `*pack`? Or `*.pack`?