# Slow boot/login -- how do I figure out the cause?

Tags: 11.04

My boot and login are a lot slower than a fresh install.

How do I trace the boot and login processes to figure out what programs are taking a long time to load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the *bootchart* package - this produces a *.png* image file showing what processes are being started and how long these processes run for.  It also describes disk-throughput which shows how efficient information is fetched from your disk.

**To install -**

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart pybootchartgui
```

Reboot and login.

Look in `/var/log/bootchart` for the image file.

for example - part of my bootchart looks like:

[image]

**To uninstall -**

```
sudo apt-get remove bootchart pybootchartgui
```

---

**Possible causes of a slow boot**

First check if you are running any unnecessary processes - for example bluetooth, modemmanager.  Also check what processes are running after login.

Its also worth [re-caching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78623/ureadahead-how-to-clear-its-cache) your `ureadahead` cache files - these files are used to speed up your boot.  Remember, remove bootchart first, reboot, remove the *.pack files and reboot twice again before reinstalling bootchart.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out which processes are doing the most I/O at any point in time, and to figure out the actual *commmand-line* of the processes? I'm seeing lots of random `sh`'s but I have no idea what they're doing, or if they're doing a lot of I/O...

Comment: Ahhh this one's a good log; [see here](http://i.imgur.com/Xwj5s.png).

Comment: nothing major in that - you could remove some unnecessary stuff like bluetooth/lmsensors/modem-manager but that wont reduce the boot greatly.  The majority of the trace is setting up the unity desktop.  This is a known issue with 11.04 & 11.10.  It has been improved greatly in 12.04

Comment: (1) I'm not using Unity though... I'm on Classic. (2) The boot is about twice as fast on a fresh install... :\

Comment: still lots of stuff launching after login though.  Try recaching your ureadahead files (http://askubuntu.com/questions/78623/ureadahead-how-to-clear-its-cache) - delete, reboot and reboot again for the cache to take effect.  Does this improve your boot time.

Comment: That folder is empty on my system (aside from a single subdirectory named `debugfs`, which is also empty)... should that be the case?

Comment: if you have in `/var/lib/ureadahead` no *.pack files (debugfs is expected) then ureadahead isnt doing its stuff to speed up your boot.  Remember to remove bootchart first and reboot a couple of times before confirming if you have a ureadahead issue.  If you do, then thats a different question... possibly you should force reinstalling i.e. `sudo apt-get --reinstall ureadahead`

Comment: Never mind, I just rebooted and I saw `pack` in there. I'll try what you mentioned and see how it goes; thanks!