# Debugging desktop loading delay

Tags: performance, debugging

Something is causing my desktop to take a long time to load (~15s). I can log in, and it displays my wallpaper, but i cant see my desktop or any menus for reasonably long period of time. How can i find out whats taking so long to load?

Im using 11.10 x64

Comment: similar if not the same as this Q&A? http://askubuntu.com/questions/90076/slow-boot-login-how-do-i-figure-out-the-cause/90085#90085

Comment: @fossfreedom That was my thought initially but looking at some bootcharts of my own, I can't see much of the graphical desktop load process reflected in it. I don't think `bootchart` will help here.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest Bootchart but I feel like it might stop logging at login.

Networking and `sshd` come up well before the desktop so you might be able to SSH in from another device and run `htop` (or `top` if you don't have `htop` installed) so you can see what is nomming on the CPU.

You've got (over) 15 seconds to inspect things - so that should be enough.

If you don't have another computer/phone you can SSH in from, you might even be able to switch to a TTY (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) and run `htop` (et al) from there while you desktop loads. It'll be harder to do but should render a similar effect.